# using spring cloud stream rabbit And when I send message the channel changed

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream

using spring cloud stream rabbit And  when I send message  the  channel changed
[image]

this my properties . the channel is `push`
But when I send message,
the channel become this `application:9002.push`

[image]

Comment: Hi, Can you show your full list of configuration properties? also, are you trying to create a source that pushes the messages into RabbitMQ exchange?

Comment: `public interface MessageOut {
 
 String PUSH = "push";
 String SMS = "sms";
 String CHALLENGE = "challenge";
 String BIND = "bind";
 
 @Output(MessageOut.PUSH)
 MessageChannel push();
 
 @Output(MessageOut.SMS)
 MessageChannel sms();

 @Output(MessageOut.CHALLENGE)
 MessageChannel challenge();

 @Output(MessageOut.BIND)
 MessageChannel bind();
}`             `### push channel
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.push.destination=receiver
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.push.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.push.group=push`

Comment: `@Autowired
 @Qualifier(MessageClient.PUSH)
 private MessageChannel push;      @Override
 public ClientResponse push(IMessage message) throws ThirdAPIException {
  try {
//   messageClient.push().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(JsonUtils.to(message)).build());
   push.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(JsonUtils.to(message)).build());
  }catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   throw new ThirdAPIException();
  }
  return ClientResponse.newInstance().ok().builder();
 }
`

Comment: Sorry, I could not figure out anything from the above. If possible, can you push your code to GitHub or somewhere I can look at?

Comment: Thanks ! I think I find it .Thank you for your help!